# C# Заполнение DataGridView данными из DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms

Структура DataGrid и DataTable идентична. При попытке записать вот так:

```
DataGridVeiw.DataSource = DataTable; //Псевдокод
```

В DatagridView справа "приклеиваются" колонки DataTable.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не советуйте заполнять циклом. Объясните в чем причина? Как грамотно и быстро заполнить Datagrid из DataTable?

Comment: в DataGridView выводятся колонки добавленные из кода и колонки из DataTable. укажите DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false; или не создавайте колонки в коде

Comment: Создавая столбцы в коде я им задаю форматирование и определенные права доступа. DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false (Столбцы просто не создадутся и результатом будет пустой грид с созданными мной столбцами).

Comment: _"Столбцы просто не создадутся"_ -- попробуйте в столбцах в коде указать к каким столбцам в DataTable надо привязаться. см. DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName

Comment: Попробую -отпишу

Answer (score 2):

Ваш "псевдокод" в принципе правильный.

Просто при заполнении DataTable давайте колонкам нормальные имена (если заполняете из БД то добавляйте в запрос AS 'ColumnName'...) например:

```
SELECT somename AS 'Имя' FROM sometable;
```

Потом:

```
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = MSB.ConnectionString;
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter adr = new MySqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
                adr.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                adr.Fill(DT);
                return DT;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Error = e.Message;
                return null;
            }
        }
```

а потом присваивайте DataTable как источник DataGridVeiw

```
DataGridVeiw.DataSource = DataTable;
DataGridVeiw.Update();
```

При этом в самом DataGridVeiw колонки создавать не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за детальный ответ. Это все я знаю. Но определенные столбцы доступны для чтения, другие для записи, для всех разное форматирование и т.д. Пожалуйста, прочитайте мой вопрос еще раз.

Comment: Так в чем проблема? Присвоили источник данных, потом выставили необходимое поведение столбцам...

Comment: Есть столбцы, которые заполняются не с источника данных. Пожалуйста, не навязывайте свое решение. Мне нужно создать столбцы, потом некоторые из них заполняются данными из источника.

Comment: Как вариант создать необходимые столбцы в DataTable до привязки

Answer (score 1):

```
// #r "System.Windows.Forms"
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;

var t = new DataTable();
t.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(int));
t.Rows.Add(1);
t.Rows.Add(2);

var f = new Form();
var g = new DataGridView() {
    Parent = f,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    AutoGenerateColumns = false
};
g.Columns.Add(
    new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() {
        DataPropertyName = "c1",   // привязка столбца грида к DataColumn
        HeaderText = "С 1"
    });
g.DataSource = t;
f.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь Stack дал верную рекомендацию. Сам искал варианты решения, но он оказался очень прост. У каждого поля DGV нужно установить параметр  DataPropertyName равным имени столбца из DataTable, который привязываете к DataSource. Всё.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема, но с DataSet.
У меня DataGridView заполнялся по нажатию кнопки, при первом вызове заполнялось нормально, при последующих - такая же проблема как и у Вас, решил с помощью очищения DataSet перед заполнением.

```
public static void ConAndSortDGV(string connectionString, string sql, DataSet ds, DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            adapter.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//номер ПЛАВКИ
    {
        ds.Clear();//необходимо для корректного обнуления таблицы при вводе данных

        string sql = $"{Properties.Settings.Default.sqlReq1} {comboBox1.Text}";
        ConAndSortDGV(connectionString, sql, ds, dataGridView1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с этим вопросом. Решение:

```
grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
grid.DataSource = bindingSource;
grid.Columns["Имя столбца в Grid"].DataPropertyName = "Имя столбца в источнике данных";
```